# How do I programmatically change workstation's ip address?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, registry, ip-address, windows-xp

There's probably some nice way of doing it (in Windows XP) in VBScript (or some other scripting language) with registry tweaks. Anyone know how?

Comment: Do you have a static address, DHCP address, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well if you don't mind just doing a regular batch script then you can use the netsh tool

It's been a while but I believe the command is something like this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name=”Local Area Connection” source=static address=<ip address> mask=<netmask> gateway=<router ip address>
```

As far as vbscript and such I have no idea but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. And, hey, I'm not going to turn my nose up that that just because it's using batch commands.